# Why does MICE fail for one dataset and not the other?

Tags: r, missing-data, multiple-imputation, mice

I am getting this error in MICE

```
Error in seq.default(1, ncol(pred)) : 'to' must be of length 1
```

My dataset is very large but I have been able to create a reproducible example with smaller subsets, one of which works, and the other of which fails with the above error:

```
dt.fail <- structure(list(hsp = c(49, 48, 42, 49, 49, 49, 50, 50, 43, 41, 43, 50, 50, 43, 45, 41, 45, 43, 50, 49), age = c(76, 83, 76, 88, 73, 41, 83, 80, 66, 56, 50, NA, 84, 46, 64, 84, 77, 69, 80, 77), sbp = c(137L, 60L, 155L, 170L, 95L, NA, 140L, 95L, 122L, 166L, 123L, 127L, 59L, 55L, 120L, 207L, 118L, 112L, 150L, 185L), hr = c(70, 90, 84, 64, 80, NA, 110, 77, 105, NA, 50, 80, 37, 38, 87, 76, 88, 93, 90, 80), CTP = c(NA, 57, NA, NA, NA, NA, 100, 142, NA, 83, 56, NA, 66, 48, 46, 88, 43, NA, 79, NA), const = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), .Names = c("hsp", "age", "sbp", "hr", "CTP", "const"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")

dt.OK <- structure(list(hsp = c(2, 1, 5, 1, 5, 4, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 5, 5, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 5, 2), age = c(65, 100, 84, 52, 70, 83, 68, 81, 91, 80, 69, 54, 92, 66, 90, 42, 78, 55, 83, 78), sbp = c(120L, 116L, 166L, 145L, 58L, NA, 146L, 156L, 130L, 110L, 83L, 162L, 101L, 135L, 118L, 130L, 122L, 136L, 115L, 115L), hr = c(68, 92, 94, 75, 143, NA, 79, 128, 90, 55, 58, 63, 95, 70, 100, 80, 59, 74, 103, 65), CTP = c(76, NA, 196, 59, 78, NA, 111, 50, NA, 60, 54, 92, 113, 65, 54, NA, 102, 53, 80, 69), const = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), .Names = c("hsp", "age", "sbp", "hr", "CTP", "const"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")

require(mice)
require(pan)

PredMatrix <- quickpred(dt.OK)
PredMatrix ["CTP",] <- c(-2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2)

imp.OK <- mice(dt.OK, meth=c("","","","","2l.pan",""), pred=PredMatrix, maxit=1, ,m=1)

imp.fail <- mice(dt.fail, meth=c("","","","","2l.pan",""), pred=PredMatrix, maxit=1, ,m=1)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks. This must be a case that is not properly detected by `mice()`. You are using `sbp` and `hr` as predictors for `CTP`. Both variable contain missing values, but are not imputed, and this may cause problems further on. Specifying `pmm` as the imputation method will make it run. Preferably, we would need a check on this condition.

Added: Inspect `imp.OK$log` and `imp.fail$log` to see the results of pre-processing the data.

Comment: OK - that's very helpful - thanks. Could you take a look at my question on SO [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14648526/diagnosing-why-r-is-crashing) ? I realise there may not be enough info in the question for you to answer but if you can let me know what else I should post (I already tried to make a small reproducible example but so far it only seems to crash on a large dataset)

Comment: I have no SO account. I occasionally have problems with the 2l methods for large data, but have never seen R itself crash on in. My guess would be that they are related to sparse data (very small clusters). If all else fails, use pmm with cluster allocation as a fixed factor, and check whether the intra-class correlations of the observed and impute data are similar. The mice package does not use any own fortran or C code.

Comment: In `mice.impute.2l.pan()` change `pred <-  x[ , type != -2 ]` into `pred <- x[,type != 2, drop = FALSE]`. Will be fixed in 2.14.

Comment: Thanks again. Is the last comment about changing the function in regard to the SO question, or this CV question ? What is the best way to make this change ? I guess `fix()` will not work ? Do I have to do `unlockBinding()`, `assignInNamespace()` etc ? As for the crashing problem I will write a post on CV shortly....

Comment: This solves the `seq.default` error. Just copy `mice.impute.2L.pan()` to `mice.impute.2L.pan2()`, do the above edit, and specify `2L.pan2` as your imputation method.

Comment: OK thanks. As for writing a new post about the crashing, I have requested that my question on SO be migrated here. I have also updated it (it dosn't seem to be related to cluter sizes)